# Chrome Extension - Run content script only when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've had a good look, but I can't seem to find and answer to this question (well, one that works for me anyway).

I've made a Chrome extension that should run the code that's in my content script on click of the icon only, but it always runs as soon as the page loads. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? None of the possible strings I can enter for run_at really cater for this.

Here is example code in both scripts:

Content Script:

```
function runIt() {
    console.log('working');
}
runIt();
```

background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content.js"});
});
```

It will log 'working' as soon as the page loads, and for each button click after that. Is there a way to stop it running as soon as the page loads?

Thanks in advance for all contributions.

Comment: chrome.tabs.executeScript doesn't let my main browser page, if i remove this it works

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `browserAction.onClicked` code in your background page does exactly what you want. If you want to stop `content.js` from running as content script on page load, simply **don't include it as a content script** in your manifest.

Specifically, in your `manifest.json` file, you have some lines that look something like this:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["*://*/*"],
    "js": ["content.js"]
  }
],
```

Simply remove those lines, and the script will stop running on page load, while your click listener code will continue working.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I tried this and it seemed to work, but I did it differently. I have accepted this as the answer though because it did what I requested, so thank you.

Comment: @DrPighouse You say you "did it differently"; You should update your question to state what change you made to get it working to help others using Chrome extensions.

Comment: chrome.tabs.executeScript doesn't let my main browser page, if i remove this it works

Comment: Doesn't removing the content script remove access for scripting within the page, though?

Comment: @metamonkey Sort of, yes, but you can also use [`tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript). In this particular case, the OP didn't want to run a page script at all; they misunderstood what content scripts are for.